# OnPressed is not working in Flutter with firebase

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, dart

There is no error in this code but doesn't work.Can someone please provide an example code of what's needed to solve for this? ➡︎
onPressed: () {widget.snapshot['twitter'];}

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

class PostDetails extends StatefulWidget {

  DocumentSnapshot snapshot;
  PostDetails({required this.snapshot});

  @override
  _PostDetailsState createState() => _PostDetailsState();
}

class _PostDetailsState extends State<PostDetails> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        leading: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios, color: Colors.redAccent),
        ),
        title: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 40,
              height: 40,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                    widget.snapshot['imgUrl'],
                  ),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 15),
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  widget.snapshot['name'],
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 3),
                Text(
                  widget.snapshot['job'],
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 13,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.black45,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.twitter),
            onPressed: () {
              widget.snapshot['twitter'];
            },
          )
        ],
        // centerTitle: false,
      ),
```

[image]

When I click the button[onPressed],I want to display  the code ---widget.snapshot['twitter'];.
What am I doing wrong here? I'd really appreciate some help. Thank you.

Comment: You said that you want to move "Twitter". What do you mean by that? Are you trying to remove the icon or navigate to Twitter?

Comment: @LalremLianBTlung 
Thank you for asking. I want to display the code -- widget.snapshot['twitter'] .
I tried remove the icon or navigate to Twitter and it's works.